# Coefficients and Expansions

Tags: binomial-coefficients

So I was just hoping for a look over my work to check if what I am doing is right because I'm not so sure:

Find the coefficient of: f$$ x^6$$ with the equation $$(3x-\frac{(1)}{x^2})^{12}$$

I have: $\sum_{i=0}^{24}  $$\binom{12}{k}(3x)^{12-k}(-x^{-2})^{k}$ and simplified it. In the end, I got k = 2.

I got $$\binom{12}{2}(3)^{10}$$ as my coefficient, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(3x-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{12} = \sum_{i=0}^{12} \binom{12}{k}(3x)^{12-k}(-x^{-2})^{k}
$$
$$
\binom{12}{k}(3x)^{12-k}(-x^{-2})^{k} = \binom{12}{k}(3)^{12-k}(x)^{12-k}(-1)^k x^{-2k} = \binom{12}{k}(3)^{12-k}(-1)^k(x)^{12-3k}
$$
$12 - 3k = 6 \rightarrow k = 2$
$$
\binom{12}{2}3^{10}x^{6}
$$

Comment: Oh yea, forgot the x part, but thank you for the clarification

Comment: The coefficient is just the number so your answer is correct Cena Maine. If it asked for the term then you'd include the power of $x$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good.

In your approach you had to solve $12-k+-2k=6$ to get $k=2$. Sometimes this isn't so obvious/easy so an alternative is to write it as:

$$\left(\frac{3x^3-1}{x^2}\right)^{12}=\frac{\left(x^3-1\right)^{12}}{x^{24}}$$

This changes the problem to finding the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in the numerator. It is then more obvious which term (and hence coefficient) you want So we need:

$${12\choose10}(3x^3)^{10}(-1)^2$$

So the coefficient is $${12\choose10}3^{10}$$

Note:${12\choose10}={12\choose2}$

Comment: Oh, ok makes sense, thanks! Also thanks for the note as well, that clears some things up

Answer (score 1):

You are right. We are looking for terms of the form $\binom {12}{A}3^Ax^A(-1)^Bx^{-2 B}$ in the binomial expansion, in which $A-2 B=6$ and $A+B=12$, which requires $A=10, B=2.$ So there is just one term, which is the one you got.

Answer (score 1):

It is   convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^j]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^j$ of a polynomial $P(x)$. We can write
\begin{align*}
[x^j]P(x)=[x^j]\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k=a_j
\end{align*}

> We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^6]&\left(3x-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{12}\\
> &=[x^6]\frac{1}{x^{24}}\left(3x^{3}-1\right)^{12}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{30}]\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}\left(3x^3\right)^k(-1)^{12-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{30}]\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}3^{k}x^{3k}(-1)^{12-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{12}{10}3^{10}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we extract $\frac{1}{x^2}$
- In (2) we expand the binomial and apply the rule $[x^n]x^{-k}P(x)=[x^{n+k}]P(x)$
- In (3) we do a small rearrangement and see that $k=10$ gives the coefficient of $x^{30}$ which we want to extract.

Comment: I see, alright, thank you!

Comment: @CenaMaine: You're welcome! :-)